# Problem with text extraction from pdf using nodejs server and reactjs webpage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-textract

The following below is my code for textractUtils.js -

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const config = require("./config");

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: config.awsAccesskeyID,
  secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretAccessKey,
  region: config.awsRegion
});

const textract = new aws.Textract();

const getText = (result, blocksMap) => {
  let text = "";

  if (_.has(result, "Relationships")) {
    result.Relationships.forEach(relationship => {
      if (relationship.Type === "CHILD") {
        relationship.Ids.forEach(childId => {
          const word = blocksMap[childId];
          if (word.BlockType === "WORD") {
            text += `${word.Text} `;
          }
          if (word.BlockType === "SELECTION_ELEMENT") {
            if (word.SelectionStatus === "SELECTED") {
              text += `X `;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  return text.trim();
};

const findValueBlock = (keyBlock, valueMap) => {
  let valueBlock;
  keyBlock.Relationships.forEach(relationship => {
    if (relationship.Type === "VALUE") {
      // eslint-disable-next-line array-callback-return
      relationship.Ids.every(valueId => {
        if (_.has(valueMap, valueId)) {
          valueBlock = valueMap[valueId];
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  });

  return valueBlock;
};

const getKeyValueRelationship = (keyMap, valueMap, blockMap) => {
  const keyValues = {};

  const keyMapValues = _.values(keyMap);

  keyMapValues.forEach(keyMapValue => {
    const valueBlock = findValueBlock(keyMapValue, valueMap);
    const key = getText(keyMapValue, blockMap);
    const value = getText(valueBlock, blockMap);
    keyValues[key] = value;
  });

  return keyValues;
};

const getKeyValueMap = blocks => {
  const keyMap = {};
  const valueMap = {};
  const blockMap = {};

  let blockId;
  blocks.forEach(block => {
    blockId = block.Id;
    blockMap[blockId] = block;

    if (block.BlockType === "KEY_VALUE_SET") {
      if (_.includes(block.EntityTypes, "KEY")) {
        keyMap[blockId] = block;
      } else {
        valueMap[blockId] = block;
      }
    }
  });

  return { keyMap, valueMap, blockMap };
};

module.exports = async buffer => {
  const params = {
    Document: {
      /* required */
      Bytes: buffer
    },
    FeatureTypes: ["FORMS"]
  };

  const request = textract.analyzeDocument(params);
  const data = await request.promise();

  if (data && data.Blocks) {
    const { keyMap, valueMap, blockMap } = getKeyValueMap(data.Blocks);
    const keyValues = getKeyValueRelationship(keyMap, valueMap, blockMap);

    return keyValues;
  }

  // in case no blocks are found return undefined
  return undefined;
};
```

It is working fine with images but not with pdf(neither single nor multi-page). The following is the error when I run it by importing pdf-

```
(node:2001) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: UnsupportedDocumentException: Request has unsupported document format
    at Request.extractError (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/home/<user>/textract-lab/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
(node:2001) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2001) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The things I have tried are a non text containing image, text containing image, table containing image, a single page pdf and a multi page pdf. I also have a conceptual doubt that if I imported the aws-sdk already , why should I code for pdf as the aws-sdk for textract looks after the image of the form pdf , png, jpeg and jpg?
What changes do I have to make to textractUtils.js for it ot process th epdf files also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AnalyzeDocument` API operation only supports images in PNG or JPEG format. From the Textract [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/limits.html#limits-document):

> Amazon Textract synchronous operations (`DetectDocumentText` and `AnalyzeDocument`) support the PNG and JPEG image formats. Asynchronous operations (`StartDocumentTextDetection`, `StartDocumentAnalysis`) also support the PDF file format.

You should use the asynchronous operations to process your PDF documents. Else, a work-around would be to convert the PDF document into images in your code and then use the synchronous API operations with these images to process the documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info but now I am facing <InvalidParameterException: Document Location parameter must contain valid bucket/name values> as I do not have S3 object access. So how to resolve this error. I checked the documentation, it states S3 object is not necessary. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: S3 permissions would not be required when using the [Bytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Document.html#Textract-Type-Document-Bytes) parameter to pass in a blob of base64-encoded document bytes. The document bytes must be in PNG or JPEG format and less than 5MB. In case you are using PDFs, then you need to specify an S3 object and have the permissions to access that object.

Comment: What do you mean by "objects are synchronous"? Always add a link to the documentation to which you refer to. If you mean that synchronous operations can use the bytes parameter, then yes you can. As stated above, you can use the synchronous operations only for PNG or JPEG file format.

Comment: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_StartDocumentAnalysis.html] Here is the link where in the error section, we see that an example is stated based on synchronous operations and pdf.

Comment: Still not sure as to what you're referring to and what you're trying to do. The documentation you linked to is for the `StartDocumentAnalysis` API operation, which is asynchronous and can process PDF documents.

Comment: I added S3 Bucket, Name (not version). Now I am getting the output as undefined. I put a few log statements. I get the jobId as output. I want the output to be the words extracted. I used getDocumentAnalysis method. data.Blocks should print the list but it returns undefined. The log statements show that data && data.Blocks returns false. Why?

Comment: It's an ***asynchronous*** call. The GetDocumentAnalysis call would contain the extracted data once the [JobStatus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_GetDocumentAnalysis.html#Textract-GetDocumentAnalysis-response-JobStatus) value is `SUCCEEDED`. Look for that value in the call, if it is returned as `IN_PROGRESS`, then you have to wait and retry. Also refer to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/api-async.html)